# jenkins error build result unstable

Tags: java, jenkins, junit

i have a problem with my jenkins please help 
generate build test but unstable , i have already  put the

```
 Error Message

    org/hamcrest/SelfDescribing
    Stacktrace

    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/SelfDescribing
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hamcrest.SelfDescribing
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add all your hamcrest-X.X.jar to your classpath?

Add hamcrest to maven dependency

Comment: My project is not a maven project and i add HAMCRESR to my classpath